# knockout ajax.beginform callback

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am using a knockout observable array in a table with each row having a delete button wrapped in a MVC Razor Ajax.BeginForm.

The delete button calls a javascript function which does a ko.utils.postJson sending the id to the server so the record gets deleted at the server and then does a remove from the viewModel so the UI is updated.

How do I do it so that I wait for the postJson before doing the client side remove? If I use the OnSuccess and OnFailure options of the Ajax.BeginForm - how do I get the relevant $data to remove from the array?

The remove function has a reference passed in but if I then do the server side first, how do I pass this reference to the OnSuccess callback?

I know I could probably code up a .ajax call in the remove function myself but would prefer the use of Ajax.BeginForm if it works.

thanks
Phil

Comment: Heya. It would help if you include code in your question that shows your scenario. It all depends on your particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Djbielejeski proposed a good approach, but if you still want to use Ajax.BeginForm to delete, you can pass parameters to OnSuccess method as well.

You just need to pass the id to your OnSuccess method. Something like this:

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("action", "controller", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = string.Format("OnSuccess({0})", rowId) }) { ... your html ... })
```

The code above assumes that rowId is an integer if it is guid or a string you will have to wrap in quotes ''.

Than in your OnSuccess function, you will get the id which will allow you to remove the element from the observable array

```
function OnSuccess(id){
  // id is available here... and you can get your viewmodel with ko.dataFor function
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wire up your delete function to the parent of the item.

For example you could do something like this

Javascript

```
var itemObject = function(data){
    var self = this;

    this.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
    .... etc ....
};

var baseViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;

    this.Items = ko.observableArray();

    this.Setup = function(items){
        //using underscore.js to map the items
        self.Items(_.map(items, function(item){
            return new itemObject(item);
        }));
    };

    this.deleteItem = function(item){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/v1/Item/" + item.Id(),
            type: "DELETE",
            success: function (data) {
                //Client side remove here
            },
            error: function (data) {
                //Whoops error time
            },
            complete: function (data) {
                //Turn of spinners or whatever here
            }
        });
    };
};

$(function(){
  var myApp = new baseViewModel();
  myApp.Setup(items);
  ko.applyBindings(myApp);
});
```

Html

```
<div data-bind="foreach: Items">
    <div data-bind="text: Id"></div>
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.deleteItem">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but as I said I knew I could probably code up ajax call. I prefer MyP3uK's answer as it takes into account the requirement to use Ajax.BeginForm